# Generalized Assignment Problem as the sub-problem

Tags: integer-programming, computational-complexity, assignment-problem

I was wondering what is the state-of-the-art for solving the Generalized Assignment Problem (GAP) and if there are special cases that are polynomially solvable?

Moreover, is there any usage of this problem as a sub-problem within a decomposition algorithm such as Lagrangian relaxation algorithms?

Answer (score 9):

I have used a GAP as a subproblem in a previous project where the aim was to solve the single source capacitated facility location problem. I tried several things in order to speed up the computations, and found that the most effective approach was to use exact knapsack separation from the capacity constraints. That is, I basically solved the dual of the "natural" column generation master.

The way I implemented it was using CPLEX by first solving the LP relaxation at the root node, then I ran several cut-loops until I experienced too much trailing off. After that, I converted the problem to an IP and added a cut callback, which used the same separation routine as I used at the root node. After experimenting a bit, I found that I got the best results this way, as CPLEX wanted to stop the cut-loop at the root node earlier than I did. I am definitely not saying this is the best way to do it, but in my experience, it worked quite okay.

But, given that it is an NP-annoying (complexity class formally defined by @prubin, I think) problem, you will have to expect that in some cases the computation time explodes!

(You can find an implementation in c of a exact knapsack separation routine here: [header](https://github.com/SuneGadegaard/SSCFLPsolver/blob/master/vico.h) [source](https://github.com/SuneGadegaard/SSCFLPsolver/blob/master/vico.c), the function you need is `VICkpsep()`)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, one of an efficient way to solve Generalized Assignment Problem (GAP),  is using Branch and Price technique. I will hope, [this](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/people/faculty/Martin_Savelsbergh/publications/or45.pdf) or [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/be5f/08847224184c4161ab1dc6fcb6dc7d28f96c.pdf) link be useful.

Comment: right, if you have a compact model in LP/MPS format, you can directly give it to e.g., GCG and it will perform branch-price-and-cut on it.